# Using undefined type

Tags: c++

```
//file list.h
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace st
{
    struct My_List;
    typedef My_List list;
    list* create(const char* name);
}

//file list.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "list.h"
namespace st
{
    struct My_List
    {
        const char* name_;
        My_List* left_;
        My_List* right_;

        My_List(const char* name):name_(name),
            left_(nullptr),
            right_(nullptr)
        {}
        My_List(const My_List&);

        ~My_List()
        {

        }
        void insert(My_List*);

        void set_name(char* name)
        {

            name_ = name;
        }

        const char* get_name()const
        {
            return name_;
        }
    };
    typedef My_List list;

    /*helper class for optor+ */
    struct MyChar
    {
        const char* my_data_;
        MyChar(const char* c_string):my_data_(c_string){}
        operator const char*()
        {
            return my_data_;
        }
        operator char*()
        {
            return const_cast<char*>(my_data_);
        }

    };

    char* operator+(MyChar left_, MyChar right_)
    {
        if (!left_.my_data_ || !right_.my_data_)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        size_t size = 1;//size is set to one for final '\0' char in an array
        char* p = "";//if both c_strings are empty this is returned
        bool has_left_ = false;
        bool has_right_ = false;
        if (strlen(left_))
        {
            size += strlen(left_);
            has_left_ = true;
        }
        if (strlen(right_))
        {
            size += strlen(right_);
            has_right_ = true;
        }
        bool both = has_left_ && has_right_ ? true : false;
        if (both)
        {
            p = new char[size]();
            const void* p_v = p;//just to keep address of beginning of p
            const char* tmp = left_;
            /*copying first c_string*/
            while (*p++ = *tmp++);

            tmp = right_;
            /*one too far after last loop*/
            --p;
            while (*p++ = *tmp++);

            *p = '\0';
            /*go back to the beginning of an array*/
            p = static_cast<char*>(const_cast<void*>(p_v));
            return p;
        }
        else if (has_left_)
        {
            return left_;
        }
        else if (has_right_)
        {
            return right_;
        }
        return p;//returns "" if both c_strings were empty
    }


    My_List::My_List(const My_List& pat):left_(nullptr),right_(nullptr)
    {
        name_ = pat.name_ + MyChar("_cpy");
        My_List* pattern = const_cast<My_List*>(&pat);
        My_List* target = this;
        while (pattern->right_)
        {

            target->right_ = static_cast<My_List*>(malloc(sizeof(My_List)));
            *target->right_ = *pattern->right_;
            target->right_->set_name(pattern->right_->get_name() + MyChar("_cpy"));
            target->right_->left_ = static_cast<My_List*>(malloc(sizeof(My_List)));
            *target->right_->left_ = *pattern->right_->left_;
            target->right_->left_->set_name(pattern->right_->left_->get_name() + MyChar("_cpy"));
            pattern = pattern->right_;
            target = target->right_;
        }
    }

    void My_List::insert(My_List* obj)
    {
        /*to catch first branch*/
        My_List* tmp = this;
        if (tmp->right_)
        {
            /*go to the end of right side*/
            while (tmp->right_)
            {
                tmp = tmp->right_;
            }

            tmp->right_ = obj;
            obj->left_ = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->right_ = obj;
            obj->left_= this;
        }
    }
    My_List* create(const char* name)
    {
        return new My_List(name);
    }
}

//file main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "list.h"
using namespace st;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    list* my = create("a");
    list* b = create("b");
    my->insert(b);//HERE I'M GETTING ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

err msg:
'Error 1 error C2027: use of undefined type 'st::My_List' 13'

Why? Especially that if I comment this line it will get compiled and create() is using this type.

Comment: terrible question name , I mean, why would anyone bother reading this(besides me), what is the problem?? Explain better -> get better answers

Comment: Try to use Classes instead of structs and declare types/classes in a readable way instead of typedefs here and there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have done only a forward declaration in header file list.h. The actual definition is in list.cpp. While compiling main.cpp you are including list.h, so compiler doesn't know what methods are there in the class My_List. You need to move the struct definition to header file list.h, you can still keep the method implementation in list.cpp

Comment: Then maybe you could "Accept" the answer :)

Comment: I didn't accept the answer at that time due to the fact that I had to leave my office, and cannot accept immediately due to the pointles time limit on accept mark. Why is there a time limit is beyond me. If there wouldn't be time limit I would accept his answer as I intended to do so but because of this ridiculous time limit I have to explain myself now instead of just accepting this button. Of course there is no point in writing to Meta - they always have very logical explanations why this is done the way it is.